# Xamarin.Forms Prism - Using navigation service to navigate from one detail page to another

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail

In my Xamarin.Forms Prism app, I am using a MasterDetailPage for navigation.

While I am on one detail page, I would like to navigate to another detail page, as if I had selected it from the master page.

Initial navigation in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   ...
   NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/RootNavigation/MyFirstPage");
}
```

When I click a shortcut button on MyFirstPage, I would like to go to MainPage/RootNavigation/MySecondPage.  The closest that I have been able to achieve has been using an absolute Uri.

```
private async void OnShortcutTapped(MyModel sender)
{
  ...
  await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://myapp.com/MainPage/RootNavigation/MySecondPage", UriKind.Absolute), navigationParams, null, false);
}
```

This basically gets me what I want, but after navigating in this manner, if I make the Master visible and select the menu item for MySecondPage, it refreshes the detail page as if it is navigating to the page.

Is there a better way to maintain this navigation, so that the master page knows that MySecondPage is already being displayed and it doesn't try to reload it?

Answer (score 1):

While your navigation pattern doesn't make a lot of sense to me, you can achieve what you want by invoking a navigate command in the MasterDetailPageViewModel.  You have a number of ways to do this.  You could use the IEventAggregator to send a message to the MasterDetailPageViewModel to navigate, or you can use a CompositeCommand that invokes a DelegateCommand that exists on the MasterDetailPageViewModel.

You can see a sample of using a CompositeCommand here:  https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/UsingCompositeCommands

You can also see how to send messages in this sample that I gave at the Xamarin Evolve conference: https://github.com/brianlagunas/Evolve2016SamplesAndSlides

Another option would be to just call a navigate command off the App.Current.MainPage ViewModel from with your MyFirstPage code behind.

Comment: I implemented the IEventAggregator to navigate on the MainPageViewModel to the given URI (RootNavigation/MySecondPage), but it seems to have the same end result as my absolute URI.  After the event handles the navigation, selecting the MySecondPage item from the Master, MySecondPage.OnNavigatedFrom and MySecondPage.OnNavigatedTo are called as if it is loading a new page.

Comment: Yes, this is to be expected. Prism nor Xamarin cache these pages. The benefit here is that you are not recreating the MasterDeatialPage.

Comment: OK, so this is the closest that can be achieved to mimicking the actual master selection?  It differs in that actually making the Master selection twice in a row does not result in OnNavigatedFrom/OnNavigatedTo, as it acts as if the second selection is ignored.

Comment: That is correct.  If you navigated to NavigationPage/ViewA, and then try to navigate to NavigationPage/ViewA again, OnNavigatedTo/From will not execute, because you aren't actually navigating. You're staying on the same view.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is then.  In my IEventAggregator, I am navigating to RootNavigation/MySecondPage.  Then when I select the MySecondPage item on the Master, the URI for the target item is RootNavigation/MySecondPage.  Why does it navigate here?

Comment: You have something going on in your app.  This does not happen in my app.